# Boot Sasmsung S7 Edge extraced Kernel from Device in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, qemu, samsung-mobile

These are Samsung S7 edge zImage and ramdisk.

```
./emulator -gpu off -verbose -avd Nexus_5X_API_24_4 -ramdisk /home/user/s7boot/boot.emmc.win-ramdisk.gz -kernel /home/user/s7boot/boot.emmc.win-zImage -show-kernel -no-snapshot-load -ranchu -wipe-data
```

But than is stays in Black Screen on Emulator and in terminal no messages.

Tried -ranchu and -qemu

With generic image from Emulator it boots:

```
generic_arm64:/ $ uname -a                                                     
Linux loca 3.10.0+ #258 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 19 12:03:16 PDT 2017 aarch64
```

Any idea how to boot that Samsung S7 Edge kernel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you can't just take a random kernel intended for one piece of Arm hardware and boot it on a different piece of Arm hardware. Because embedded/mobile Arm systems differ so much, typically operating system or firmware images intended to run on one machine will not run at all on any other. This is often surprising for new users who are used to the x86 world where every system looks like a standard PC.

So you need to match the emulator machine type you're using with the kernel image. The Android emulator doesn't model a Samsung S7, so you need to use a generic kernel or one specifically targeting the machine model the emulator provides.