# Booting Kernel in QEMU - PFLASH: Possible BUG - Write block confirm

Tags: qemu

Trying to boot a Samsung S7 Edge Kernel 3.18.x using QEMU

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -kernel s7boot/boot.emmc.win-zImage -machine virt  -cpu cortex-a5
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
PFLASH: Possible BUG - Write block confirm
```

And QEMU exits.

What could be the cause and the solution to this?

Thanks,

P.S Related to this:

[Boot Sasmsung S7 Edge extraced Kernel from Device in Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658541/boot-sasmsung-s7-edge-extraced-kernel-from-device-in-android-emulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was recently fixed in QEMU (in release 4.0.0) with the [following commit](https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=commitdiff;h=2d93bebf81520ccebeb9a3ea9bd051ce088854ea).

The commit message says that aborting FLASH interface command "write to buffer" is not supported by QEMU pflash_cfi01 model. QEMU 4.0.0 and newer will still print the message but will not terminate emulation, one possible solution to your issue is to update QEMU version or to backport the fix. Another is to find a place where the kernel tries to abort write to buffer command and see if it can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my QEMU. Now the error is gone, but still see blank screen. Do I invoke QEMU correctly. I opened another questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58688656/booting-android-samsung-kernel-in-qemu