# Booting Android (Samsung) Kernel in QEMU

Tags: android, qemu

Trying to boot a Samsung S7 Edge Kernel 3.18.x using QEMU

```
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-aarch64  -M virt -cpu cortex-a57  -kernel $HOME/s7boot/boot.emmc.win-zImage -initrd $HOME/s7boot/boot.emmc.win-ramdisk.gz -nographic
```

Nothing happens

Screen remains as it was.

CPU is at 100% for QEMU process

Using QEMU

```
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 --version
QEMU emulator version 4.1.0
Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

Trying it with -s -S

```
 /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-aarch64  -M virt -cpu cortex-a57  -kernel $HOME/s7boot/boot.emmc.win-zImage -initrd $HOME/s7boot/boot.emmc.win-ramdisk.gz -nographic -s -S
```

GDB

```
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) target remote:1234
Remote debugging using :1234
warning: while parsing target description (at line 1): Target description specified unknown architecture "aarch64"
warning: Could not load XML target description; ignoring
0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x40080000 in ?? ()
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
```

So I guess it get stuck at 0x4008000

Anynway .... I tried serveral Kernels (downloaded from device, LineageOS, Some other custom, also compiled one from Samsung Sources) with no luck.

Questions:

Anybody booted Samsung/Android Kernel in QEMU?

Thanks,

Related to:

[Booting Kernel in QEMU - PFLASH: Possible BUG - Write block confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679094/booting-kernel-in-qemu-pflash-possible-bug-write-block-confirm/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same question as [Boot Sasmsung S7 Edge extraced Kernel from Device in Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658541/boot-sasmsung-s7-edge-extraced-kernel-from-device-in-android-emulator) but for QEMU proper rather than the Android emulator, and the answer is the same -- you need a kernel that's been built to run on the machine type you're using, which in this case is the "virt" board. Trying to boot a random kernel pulled off a different hardware device is never going to work.